# species ID: garden bush from Bangalore, India

Tags: species-identification, botany

Please help to identify this plant. It is a garden bush growing in soil. The pictures were taken in Bangalore, India.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Comment: Please include your question where you found it, if it is wild or growing in a garden or pot, and include the photo in the question. [See](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info)

Comment: The plant was found in India, near Bangalore. It is a garden growing bush.

Answer (score 1):

Could be anything, if it's ornamental. However, it would appear to be some kind of Pinaceae or other evergreen conifer. Possibly a juvenile hemlock or araucaria. I know that in Northern India there is *Tsuga dumosa* [image]

Maybe an *Araucaria*? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Those pointed, awl-shaped leaves strike me much more as a member of [Cupressaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupressaceae) than the other conifers mentioned (Pinaceae, Araucariaceae). If I had to guess, I'd say some kind of juniper, [*Juniperus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniper), though there are many other possibilities.

Are there any other features available, like berries or cones?